# Fastest postgreSQL equivalent to MySQL UTC_DATE() (getting UTC date)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I am new to postgreSQL and to my surprise there appears to be no single function equivalent to `UTC_DATE()` from MySQL.

I was able to get desired result using a combination of date & timezone functions but I am wondering what is the fastest way to do this.

I just  want to get **UTC** date part, at **00:00:00** time of current day.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the time zone capability of PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(NOW() at time zone 'utc' AS date);
```

Comment: Could you also use `NOW() without time zone`?

Comment: is it the best way? Im thinking that in C# DateTime.Now is using DateTime.UtcNow first and then applying timezone, I just suspected it might be doing something like this in postgre.. I am currently using date(timezone('UTC', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) is there any performance difference with this?

Comment: @Doug Kress: No, the statements `select now() at time zone 'utc';` and `select now()::timestamp without time zone;` return different values. The difference is that `now() at time zone` applies the difference in hours between now and UTC; `now()::timestamp without time zone` does not.