# What is the equivalence of MS SQL Server's getutcdate() in postgresql?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I migrate from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. How to translate the getutcdate function like:

```
Insert into mytable (mypk, toucheddate) values (99, getutcdate() )
```

(I'm not asking for an equivalent to MySQL, this is a different platform)

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143505/fastest-postgresql-equivalent-to-mysql-utc-date-getting-utc-date

Comment: It gives a hint but it doesn't answer my question since I don't know if the MySQL function is an equivalent to the SQL Server function. My question was not precise enough, edit just done.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are at least two ways to get the current time in UTC:

```
select now() at time zone 'utc';

select current_timestamp at time zone 'utc';
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has `current_timestamp` for the current date and time, `current_date` for the current date and `current_time` for the current time.

Additional details can be found in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html).

Comment: This is not in UTC, but local time. Needs to be `current_timestamp at time zone 'utc'`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `now()`:

```
postgres=# select now();
            now
---------------------------
 2015-05-05 13:52:45.81-04
(1 row)
```

Comment: This is not enough, since they wanted UTC time. This gives local time. Needs to be `now() at time zone 'utc'`